# cmake v3.15.3 cannot find boost v1.71.0

Tags: boost, cmake

I am trying to build from source the following software in Windows 10: https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua. I have also installed the latest version of the boost libraries (`boost_1_71_0`) but when I try to use CMake for compiling the source code, CMake cannot find the location of boost.

Environment: Windows 10
CMake version: 3.15.3
boost version: 1.71.0

1. I have downloaded the latest version of boost from this link: https://dl.bintray.com/boostorg/release/1.71.0/source/boost_1_71_0.zip
2. I have extracted the content.
3. Inside the extracted folder I have executed: `.\bootstrap.bat`
4. After bootstrap has finished I have executed: `.\b2`
5. After `b2` finished, I changed to the extracted directory for FreeOpcUa and created a build directory: `mkdir build`
6. I changed to the new directory: `cd ./build`
7. I tried to compile the source with: `cmake .. -DBOOST_ROOT="C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_71_0"`

CMake prompts the following:

```
cmake .. -DBOOST_ROOT="C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_71_0"  
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015  
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.14393.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.  
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1  
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1  
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe  
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works  
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info  
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done  
-- Detecting C compile features  
-- Detecting C compile features - done  
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe  
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works  
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info  
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done  
-- Detecting CXX compile features  
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done  
-- Looking for pthread.h  
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found  
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):  
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: system program_options filesystem thread)  
  (found version "1.71.0")  
Call Stack (most recent call first):  
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)  
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2161 (find_package_handle_standard_args)  
  CMakeLists.txt:108 (find_package)  


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!  
See also "C:/Users/Dunkes/Desktop/C++_SDKs/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".  
See also "C:/Users/Dunkes/Desktop/C++_SDKs/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

As user @Tsyvarev has suggested, if I run CMake with the `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` option I get the following:

```
-- Building for: Visual Studio 14 2015
-- Selecting Windows SDK version 10.0.14393.0 to target Windows 10.0.18362.
-- The C compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- The CXX compiler identification is MSVC 19.0.24215.1
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1446 ] _boost_TEST_VERSIONS = "1.71.0;1.71;1.70.0;1.70;1.69.0;1.69;1.68.0;1.68;1.67.0;1.67;1.66.0;1.66;1.65.1;1.65.0;1.65;1.64.0;1.64;1.63.0;1.63;1.62.0;1.62;1.61.0;1.61;1.60.0;1.60;1.59.0;1.59;1.58.0;1.58;1.57.0;1.57;1.56.0;1.56;1.55.0;1.55;1.54.0;1.54;1.53.0;1.53;1.52.0;1.52;1.51.0;1.51;1.50.0;1.50;1.49.0;1.49;1.48.0;1.48;1.47.0;1.47;1.46.1;1.46.0;1.46;1.45.0;1.45;1.44.0;1.44;1.43.0;1.43;1.42.0;1.42;1.41.0;1.41;1.40.0;1.40;1.39.0;1.39;1.38.0;1.38;1.37.0;1.37;1.36.1;1.36.0;1.36;1.35.1;1.35.0;1.35;1.34.1;1.34.0;1.34;1.33.1;1.33.0;1.33"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1447 ] Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED = "TRUE"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1448 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1449 ] Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1450 ] Boost_ADDITIONAL_VERSIONS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1451 ] Boost_NO_SYSTEM_PATHS = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1520 ] BOOST_ROOT = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1521 ] ENV{BOOST_ROOT} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1522 ] BOOST_INCLUDEDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1523 ] ENV{BOOST_INCLUDEDIR} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1524 ] BOOST_LIBRARYDIR = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1525 ] ENV{BOOST_LIBRARYDIR} = <unset>
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1597 ] _boost_INCLUDE_SEARCH_DIRS = "PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_71_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_71;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_70_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_70;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_69_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_69;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_68_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_68;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_67_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_67;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_66_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_66;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_65_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_65_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_65;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_64_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_64;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_63_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_63;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_62_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_62;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_61_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_61;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_60_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_60;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_59_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_59;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_58_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_58;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_57_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_57;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_56_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_56;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_55_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_55;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_54_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_54;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_53_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_53;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_52_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_52;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_51_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_51;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_50_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_50;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_49_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_49;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_48_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_48;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_47_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_47;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_46_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_46_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_46;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_45_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_45;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_44_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_44;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_43_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_43;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_42_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_42;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_41_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_41;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_40_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_40;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_39_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_39;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_38_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_38;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_37_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_37;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_36_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_36_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_36;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_35_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_35_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_35;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_34_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_34_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_34;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_33_1;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_33_0;PATHS;C:/local/boost_1_33;PATHS;C:/boost/include;C:/boost;/sw/local/include"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1598 ] _boost_PATH_SUFFIXES = "boost-1_71_0;boost_1_71_0;boost/boost-1_71_0;boost/boost_1_71_0;boost-1_71;boost_1_71;boost/boost-1_71;boost/boost_1_71;boost-1_70_0;boost_1_70_0;boost/boost-1_70_0;boost/boost_1_70_0;boost-1_70;boost_1_70;boost/boost-1_70;boost/boost_1_70;boost-1_69_0;boost_1_69_0;boost/boost-1_69_0;boost/boost_1_69_0;boost-1_69;boost_1_69;boost/boost-1_69;boost/boost_1_69;boost-1_68_0;boost_1_68_0;boost/boost-1_68_0;boost/boost_1_68_0;boost-1_68;boost_1_68;boost/boost-1_68;boost/boost_1_68;boost-1_67_0;boost_1_67_0;boost/boost-1_67_0;boost/boost_1_67_0;boost-1_67;boost_1_67;boost/boost-1_67;boost/boost_1_67;boost-1_66_0;boost_1_66_0;boost/boost-1_66_0;boost/boost_1_66_0;boost-1_66;boost_1_66;boost/boost-1_66;boost/boost_1_66;boost-1_65_1;boost_1_65_1;boost/boost-1_65_1;boost/boost_1_65_1;boost-1_65_0;boost_1_65_0;boost/boost-1_65_0;boost/boost_1_65_0;boost-1_65;boost_1_65;boost/boost-1_65;boost/boost_1_65;boost-1_64_0;boost_1_64_0;boost/boost-1_64_0;boost/boost_1_64_0;boost-1_64;boost_1_64;boost/boost-1_64;boost/boost_1_64;boost-1_63_0;boost_1_63_0;boost/boost-1_63_0;boost/boost_1_63_0;boost-1_63;boost_1_63;boost/boost-1_63;boost/boost_1_63;boost-1_62_0;boost_1_62_0;boost/boost-1_62_0;boost/boost_1_62_0;boost-1_62;boost_1_62;boost/boost-1_62;boost/boost_1_62;boost-1_61_0;boost_1_61_0;boost/boost-1_61_0;boost/boost_1_61_0;boost-1_61;boost_1_61;boost/boost-1_61;boost/boost_1_61;boost-1_60_0;boost_1_60_0;boost/boost-1_60_0;boost/boost_1_60_0;boost-1_60;boost_1_60;boost/boost-1_60;boost/boost_1_60;boost-1_59_0;boost_1_59_0;boost/boost-1_59_0;boost/boost_1_59_0;boost-1_59;boost_1_59;boost/boost-1_59;boost/boost_1_59;boost-1_58_0;boost_1_58_0;boost/boost-1_58_0;boost/boost_1_58_0;boost-1_58;boost_1_58;boost/boost-1_58;boost/boost_1_58;boost-1_57_0;boost_1_57_0;boost/boost-1_57_0;boost/boost_1_57_0;boost-1_57;boost_1_57;boost/boost-1_57;boost/boost_1_57;boost-1_56_0;boost_1_56_0;boost/boost-1_56_0;boost/boost_1_56_0;boost-1_56;boost_1_56;boost/boost-1_56;boost/boost_1_56;boost-1_55_0;boost_1_55_0;boost/boost-1_55_0;boost/boost_1_55_0;boost-1_55;boost_1_55;boost/boost-1_55;boost/boost_1_55;boost-1_54_0;boost_1_54_0;boost/boost-1_54_0;boost/boost_1_54_0;boost-1_54;boost_1_54;boost/boost-1_54;boost/boost_1_54;boost-1_53_0;boost_1_53_0;boost/boost-1_53_0;boost/boost_1_53_0;boost-1_53;boost_1_53;boost/boost-1_53;boost/boost_1_53;boost-1_52_0;boost_1_52_0;boost/boost-1_52_0;boost/boost_1_52_0;boost-1_52;boost_1_52;boost/boost-1_52;boost/boost_1_52;boost-1_51_0;boost_1_51_0;boost/boost-1_51_0;boost/boost_1_51_0;boost-1_51;boost_1_51;boost/boost-1_51;boost/boost_1_51;boost-1_50_0;boost_1_50_0;boost/boost-1_50_0;boost/boost_1_50_0;boost-1_50;boost_1_50;boost/boost-1_50;boost/boost_1_50;boost-1_49_0;boost_1_49_0;boost/boost-1_49_0;boost/boost_1_49_0;boost-1_49;boost_1_49;boost/boost-1_49;boost/boost_1_49;boost-1_48_0;boost_1_48_0;boost/boost-1_48_0;boost/boost_1_48_0;boost-1_48;boost_1_48;boost/boost-1_48;boost/boost_1_48;boost-1_47_0;boost_1_47_0;boost/boost-1_47_0;boost/boost_1_47_0;boost-1_47;boost_1_47;boost/boost-1_47;boost/boost_1_47;boost-1_46_1;boost_1_46_1;boost/boost-1_46_1;boost/boost_1_46_1;boost-1_46_0;boost_1_46_0;boost/boost-1_46_0;boost/boost_1_46_0;boost-1_46;boost_1_46;boost/boost-1_46;boost/boost_1_46;boost-1_45_0;boost_1_45_0;boost/boost-1_45_0;boost/boost_1_45_0;boost-1_45;boost_1_45;boost/boost-1_45;boost/boost_1_45;boost-1_44_0;boost_1_44_0;boost/boost-1_44_0;boost/boost_1_44_0;boost-1_44;boost_1_44;boost/boost-1_44;boost/boost_1_44;boost-1_43_0;boost_1_43_0;boost/boost-1_43_0;boost/boost_1_43_0;boost-1_43;boost_1_43;boost/boost-1_43;boost/boost_1_43;boost-1_42_0;boost_1_42_0;boost/boost-1_42_0;boost/boost_1_42_0;boost-1_42;boost_1_42;boost/boost-1_42;boost/boost_1_42;boost-1_41_0;boost_1_41_0;boost/boost-1_41_0;boost/boost_1_41_0;boost-1_41;boost_1_41;boost/boost-1_41;boost/boost_1_41;boost-1_40_0;boost_1_40_0;boost/boost-1_40_0;boost/boost_1_40_0;boost-1_40;boost_1_40;boost/boost-1_40;boost/boost_1_40;boost-1_39_0;boost_1_39_0;boost/boost-1_39_0;boost/boost_1_39_0;boost-1_39;boost_1_39;boost/boost-1_39;boost/boost_1_39;boost-1_38_0;boost_1_38_0;boost/boost-1_38_0;boost/boost_1_38_0;boost-1_38;boost_1_38;boost/boost-1_38;boost/boost_1_38;boost-1_37_0;boost_1_37_0;boost/boost-1_37_0;boost/boost_1_37_0;boost-1_37;boost_1_37;boost/boost-1_37;boost/boost_1_37;boost-1_36_1;boost_1_36_1;boost/boost-1_36_1;boost/boost_1_36_1;boost-1_36_0;boost_1_36_0;boost/boost-1_36_0;boost/boost_1_36_0;boost-1_36;boost_1_36;boost/boost-1_36;boost/boost_1_36;boost-1_35_1;boost_1_35_1;boost/boost-1_35_1;boost/boost_1_35_1;boost-1_35_0;boost_1_35_0;boost/boost-1_35_0;boost/boost_1_35_0;boost-1_35;boost_1_35;boost/boost-1_35;boost/boost_1_35;boost-1_34_1;boost_1_34_1;boost/boost-1_34_1;boost/boost_1_34_1;boost-1_34_0;boost_1_34_0;boost/boost-1_34_0;boost/boost_1_34_0;boost-1_34;boost_1_34;boost/boost-1_34;boost/boost_1_34;boost-1_33_1;boost_1_33_1;boost/boost-1_33_1;boost/boost_1_33_1;boost-1_33_0;boost_1_33_0;boost/boost-1_33_0;boost/boost_1_33_0;boost-1_33;boost_1_33;boost/boost-1_33;boost/boost_1_33"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1613 ] location of version.hpp: C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/boost/version.hpp
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1653 ] Boost_VERSION = "107100"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1654 ] Boost_VERSION_STRING = "1.71.0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1655 ] Boost_VERSION_MACRO = "107100"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1656 ] Boost_VERSION_MAJOR = "1"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1657 ] Boost_VERSION_MINOR = "71"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1658 ] Boost_VERSION_PATCH = "0"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1659 ] Boost_VERSION_COUNT = "3"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1676 ] Boost_LIB_PREFIX = ""
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1677 ] Boost_NAMESPACE = "boost"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:787 ] _boost_COMPILER = "-vc140" (guessed)
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1713 ] _boost_MULTITHREADED = "-mt"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1790 ] _boost_ARCHITECTURE_TAG = "-x32" (detected)
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1794 ] _boost_RELEASE_ABI_TAG = "-"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1795 ] _boost_DEBUG_ABI_TAG = "-gd"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1855 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = "C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/../lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/stage/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/../lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_69/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_67/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_66/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_54_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_54/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_53_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_53/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_52_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_52/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_51_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_51/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_50_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_50/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_49_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_49/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_48_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_48/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_47_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_47/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_45_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_45/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_44_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_44/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_43_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_43/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_42_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_42/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_41_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_41/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_40_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_40/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_39_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_39/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_38_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_38/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_37_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_37/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib32-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1856 ] _boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_DEBUG = "C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/../lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/stage/lib;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/../lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_71/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_70/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_69_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_69/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_68_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_68/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_67_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_67/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_66_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_66/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_65/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_64/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_63/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_62/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_61/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_60/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_59/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_58/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_57/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_56/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_55/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_54_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_54/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_53_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_53/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_52_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_52/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_51_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_51/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_50_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_50/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_49_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_49/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_48_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_48/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_47_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_47/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_46/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_45_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_45/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_44_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_44/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_43_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_43/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_42_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_42/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_41_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_41/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_40_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_40/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_39_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_39/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_38_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_38/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_37_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_37/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_36/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_35/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_34/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33_1/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/local/boost_1_33/lib32-msvc-14.0;C:/boost/lib32-msvc-14.0;PATHS;C:/boost/lib;C:/boost;/sw/local/lib"
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - not found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2040 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_system-vc140-mt-x32-1_71;boost_system-vc140-mt-x32;boost_system-vc140-mt;boost_system-mt-x32-1_71;boost_system-mt-x32;boost_system-mt;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2095 ] Searching for SYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd-x32;boost_system-vc140-mt-gd;boost_system-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_system-mt-gd-x32;boost_system-mt-gd;boost_system-mt;boost_system
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2040 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_program_options-vc140-mt-x32-1_71;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-x32;boost_program_options-vc140-mt;boost_program_options-mt-x32-1_71;boost_program_options-mt-x32;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2095 ] Searching for PROGRAM_OPTIONS_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd-x32;boost_program_options-vc140-mt-gd;boost_program_options-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_program_options-mt-gd-x32;boost_program_options-mt-gd;boost_program_options-mt;boost_program_options
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2040 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-x32-1_71;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-x32;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt;boost_filesystem-mt-x32-1_71;boost_filesystem-mt-x32;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2095 ] Searching for FILESYSTEM_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd-x32;boost_filesystem-vc140-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_filesystem-mt-gd-x32;boost_filesystem-mt-gd;boost_filesystem-mt;boost_filesystem
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2040 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_thread-vc140-mt-x32-1_71;boost_thread-vc140-mt-x32;boost_thread-vc140-mt;boost_thread-mt-x32-1_71;boost_thread-mt-x32;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2095 ] Searching for THREAD_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd-x32;boost_thread-vc140-mt-gd;boost_thread-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_thread-mt-gd-x32;boost_thread-mt-gd;boost_thread-mt;boost_thread
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2040 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_chrono-vc140-mt-x32-1_71;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-x32;boost_chrono-vc140-mt;boost_chrono-mt-x32-1_71;boost_chrono-mt-x32;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2095 ] Searching for CHRONO_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd-x32;boost_chrono-vc140-mt-gd;boost_chrono-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_chrono-mt-gd-x32;boost_chrono-mt-gd;boost_chrono-mt;boost_chrono
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2040 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_date_time-vc140-mt-x32-1_71;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-x32;boost_date_time-vc140-mt;boost_date_time-mt-x32-1_71;boost_date_time-mt-x32;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2095 ] Searching for DATE_TIME_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd-x32;boost_date_time-vc140-mt-gd;boost_date_time-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_date_time-mt-gd-x32;boost_date_time-mt-gd;boost_date_time-mt;boost_date_time
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2040 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_RELEASE: boost_atomic-vc140-mt-x32-1_71;boost_atomic-vc140-mt-x32;boost_atomic-vc140-mt;boost_atomic-mt-x32-1_71;boost_atomic-mt-x32;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic
-- [ C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2095 ] Searching for ATOMIC_LIBRARY_DEBUG: boost_atomic-vc140-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_atomic-vc140-mt-gd-x32;boost_atomic-vc140-mt-gd;boost_atomic-mt-gd-x32-1_71;boost_atomic-mt-gd-x32;boost_atomic-mt-gd;boost_atomic-mt;boost_atomic
CMake Error at C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find Boost (missing: system program_options filesystem thread)
  (found version "1.71.0")
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:378 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  C:/Program Files/CMake/share/cmake-3.15/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:2161 (find_package_handle_standard_args)
  CMakeLists.txt:108 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "C:/Users/Dunkes/Desktop/C++_SDKs/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "C:/Users/Dunkes/Desktop/C++_SDKs/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua-master/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

Comment: As [documentation for FindBoost](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindBoost.html) suggests, run cmake with `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON` option to see more detailed output about finding Boost.

Comment: Thank you so much for your quick response. I have updated the post.

Comment: Well, with `Boost_DEBUG` setting you know which **directories** are searched (`_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE` lists them) and which **exact files** are searched (e.g. `SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE` for `system` component). Do you actually have these files/directories in your Boost installation? Or do you have some other directories or files with slightly different names?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: If am not wrong, for the boost version that I have installed (1.71.1), CMake is looking for the following directories as indicated by `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE`:

`_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE = 
"C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/lib;
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/../lib;
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/stage/lib;
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/../lib32-msvc-14.0;
C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;
C:/local/boost_1_71_0/lib32-msvc-14.0;
C:/local/boost_1_71/lib32-msvc-14.0;`

Comment: I didn't mean that you are wrong. I asked you to check the files and directories, which you **actually** have in your Boost installation, and compare them with the CMake output. While we both see that CMake output, only you see the Boost files on your machine.

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Sorry for the misunderstanding I wanted to say **If am not wrong**, not "I am not wrong". And the only path that I can find in my local boost directory is the first one: `C:/Program Files/boost/boost_1_71_0/lib`. So, I am assuming that boost is not correctly compiled.

Comment: This is not a problem: CMake search in **every** directory listed in the `_boost_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DIRS_RELEASE`. As you have at least one existed on your machine, then this is OK. Then, what about the **files** in that directory, do you actually have the one corresponded to one of the files, listed in `SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE` variable? Or do you have a file with similar, but different name?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Instead the files listed in `SYSTEM_LIBRARY_RELEASE`, I have one called: `libboost_system-vc140-mt-x32-1_71`.

Comment: So you actually have **static** Boost libraries (this is a meaning of `lib` prefix). Probably, you need to additionally pass `-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON` to `cmake`. You may try also other options, listed in the [FindBoost documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.15/module/FindBoost.html).

Comment: With `DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON` is no longer complaining about system, now it says:  `Could NOT find Boost (missing: program_options filesystem thread) (found
  version "1.71.0")`. So now, I have to look for program_options, filesystem and thread components.

Comment: Yes, now you need to check, whether you have these components in your Boost installation.

Answer (score 10):

You need to set `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` in addition to `BOOST_ROOT`, e.g.:

```
cmake .. -DBOOST_ROOT="C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_71_0" -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR="C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_71_0"
```

So that `cmake` can find the library binaries you built with:

```
bjam.exe install --prefix="C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_71_0" --with-system --with-date_time --with-random link=static runtime-link=shared threading=multi
```

Note: the `bjam` command above should have built the `boost` library files in your
`C:\Program Files\boost\boost_1_71_0\lib` directory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I copied the `bjam` installation command from another source and I did not know that I was only building certain libraries of `boost` and not the ones that I actually needed for my `CMakeLists.txt`. In the end, I edited my original post to build all the `boost` libraries.

Answer (score 7):

Ok, so in the end the solution was to use the flag `-DBoost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=ON` to tell `CMake` to look for the **STATIC** libs. Many thanks to @Tsyvarev for his invaluable help.

Answer (score 1):

For those of you that built from source using the Visual Studio command prompt, note that the default value for `Boost_COMPILER` is `"-vc"`, even though your libraries were built with names like `"-vc141"` (example for Visual Studio 2017).

Set `Boost_COMPILER` to the correct value before calling `find_package(Boost)` and see if that takes care of the problem.

Finally unearthed this after a few hours of frustration.

Answer (score 0):

for those who install boost using vcpkg, dont forget to add the toolchain. while the error seems to find the boost, it's file structure is totally different, thus producing confusing results making you think you need to add boost_use_static=on or like. just add vcpkg.cmake toolchain. add vcpkg to path is not enough and as time pass, you might forget just like me.

to add vcpkg toolchain, just use

```
-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=[vcpkg root]/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake
```

for more information, visit https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg#vcpkg-as-a-submodule

Comment: What do you mean by "add the vcpkage.cmake toolchain"? Can you please be more specific with what I should do?