# Failed to build Freeopcua c++

Tags: c++, opc-ua

I am trying to build opcua from source: https://github.com/FreeOpcUa/freeopcua in Windows 10:

According to the answer given by:[cmake v3.15.3 cannot find boost v1.71.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57870032/cmake-v3-15-3-cannot-find-boost-v1-71-0), I successfully compiled the source and got freeopcua.sln in my build folder.

However when I tried to build the projects through Visual Studio 2019, I got the errors below:
[Output from VS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdRfb.png)

I also tried to run `cmake --build .` then I got the same error.

```html
E:\freeopcua\src\core\common\uri_facade_win.cpp(23,1): error C2511: 'void Common::Uri::Initialize(const char *,size_t)': overloaded member fun
ction not found in 'Common::Uri' [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/common/uri_facade.h(18): message : see declaration of 'Common::Uri' [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\common\uri_facade_win.cpp(34,6): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'DWORD', possible loss of data [
E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\common\uri_facade_win.cpp(40,79): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Common::Uri::SchemeStr' [E:\freeo
pcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\common\uri_facade_win.cpp(41,83): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Common::Uri::UserStr' [E:\freeopc
ua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\common\uri_facade_win.cpp(42,87): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Common::Uri::PasswordStr' [E:\fre
eopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\common\uri_facade_win.cpp(43,83): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Common::Uri::HostStr' [E:\freeopc
ua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
  value.cpp
  event.cpp
E:\freeopcua\src\core\common\uri_facade_win.cpp(44,22): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member 'Common::Uri::PortNum' [E:\freeopc
ua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/protocol/data_value.h(24,42): warning C4245: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t', signed/unsigned m
ismatch [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
  model_node.cpp
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/node.h(88,32): warning C4101: 'e': unreferenced local variable [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
  model_object.cpp
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/protocol/data_value.h(24,42): warning C4245: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t', signed/unsigned m
ismatch [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/protocol/data_value.h(24,42): warning C4245: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t', signed/unsigned m
ismatch [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\model_object.cpp(111,48): warning C4100: 'name': unreferenced formal parameter [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\model_object.cpp(116,47): warning C4100: 'name': unreferenced formal parameter [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\model_object.cpp(299,88): warning C4100: 'type': unreferenced formal parameter [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\model_object.cpp(299,55): warning C4100: 'browseName': unreferenced formal parameter [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxpr
oj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\model_object.cpp(304,118): warning C4100: 'type': unreferenced formal parameter [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\model_object.cpp(304,85): warning C4100: 'browseName': unreferenced formal parameter [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxpr
oj]
  model_object_type.cpp
E:\freeopcua\src\core\model_object.cpp(304,48): warning C4100: 'newVariableId': unreferenced formal parameter [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vc
xproj]
  model_server.cpp
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/protocol/data_value.h(24,42): warning C4245: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t', signed/unsigned m
ismatch [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
  model_variable.cpp
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/protocol/data_value.h(24,42): warning C4245: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t', signed/unsigned m
ismatch [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
  node.cpp
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/protocol/data_value.h(24,42): warning C4245: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t', signed/unsigned m
ismatch [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/protocol/data_value.h(24,42): warning C4245: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t', signed/unsigned m
ismatch [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/node.h(88,32): warning C4101: 'e': unreferenced local variable [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\node.cpp(257,25): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'uint16_t', possible loss of data [E:\fre
eopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\node.cpp(332,36): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'uint16_t', possible loss of data [E:\freeopc
ua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\node.cpp(372,36): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'uint16_t', possible loss of data [E:\freeopc
ua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\node.cpp(404,36): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'uint16_t', possible loss of data [E:\freeopc
ua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\node.cpp(457,36): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'uint16_t', possible loss of data [E:\freeopc
ua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
  opcua_errors.cpp
  socket_channel.cpp
E:\freeopcua\src\core\node.cpp(507,36): warning C4244: 'argument': conversion from 'uint32_t' to 'uint16_t', possible loss of data [E:\freeopc
ua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\socket_channel.cpp(53,3): error C3861: 'close': identifier not found [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\src\core\socket_channel.cpp(58,54): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\freeo
pcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
  subscription.cpp
E:\freeopcua\src\core\socket_channel.cpp(75,43): warning C4267: 'argument': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\freeo
pcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/protocol/data_value.h(24,42): warning C4245: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t', signed/unsigned m
ismatch [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
  Generating Code...
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/node.h(88,32): warning C4101: 'e': unreferenced local variable [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
  Compiling...
  server_operations.cpp
E:\freeopcua\src\core\node.cpp(207): warning C4702: unreachable code [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/protocol/data_value.h(24,42): warning C4245: 'initializing': conversion from 'int' to 'uint8_t', signed/unsigned m
ismatch [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
  Generating Code...
E:\freeopcua\include\opc/ua/node.h(88,32): warning C4101: 'e': unreferenced local variable [E:\freeopcua\build\opcuacore.vcxproj]
```

Comment: It looks like the maintainers have made interface changes without updating the Windows-specific parts.

Comment: Is there some method to solve this? Sorry that I don't know much about debugging in compiling

Comment: There seems to be pull requests fixing this that haven't been merged. You might be able to merge those into a branch of your own.

Comment: Thanks. But already tried it and failed. Seems like the patch still has some problem

Comment: @Valeria96 does applying the pull request change sets cause any difference in the failures?